# create sql server login for own domain account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, logins

I have a working SQL Server instance to administer.  I do not have a SQL Server login and do not know any other logins. I do have a Windows domain login to the server as a local admin.  How can I add my Windows account as a login to SQL Server when I don't know any existing login to the instance?

I can connect using PowerShell:

```
cd sql\uk-blahblah\default\logins
```

but cannot retrieve any detail:

```
gci

SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Failed to read child items. [Failed to connect to server uk-blahblah. --> Login failed for user 'AUTOdomain\admin-account'.]
```

I can stop the SQL Service and restart from an elevated command prompt:

```
sqlservr.exe -m -c
```

but trying to run sqlcmd still fails:

```
sqlcmd -S UK-blahblah
Login failed for user 'AUTOdomain\admin-account'
```

I'm sure many of you must have found a way of adding your login to a server where you don't know any other logins, but I'm struggling a little here.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 SP2 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several workarounds listed in the following articles:

- [Recover Access to a SQL Server Instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/)
- [More on Recovering Access to a SQL Server Instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4672/more-on-recovering-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/)

The more tedious workaround is detailed in the latter article, and should be used with extreme caution on a production server (totally fine for your own workstation):

1. In the Services applet, stop the SQL Server VSS Writer service
2. Place a copy of SQLCMD.exe in the VSS Writer folder
3. Rename SqlWriter.exe to SqlWriter.exe.old
4. Rename SQLCMD.exe to SqlWriter.exe
5. Change the registry entry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SQLWriter` so that the path includes arguments such as `-S.\instance -E -Q"ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin..."` where you can add logins to the `sysadmin` role.
6. Start the service again. It will fail to start, but the `ALTER` command will have been sent to the server.
7. Delete SqlWriter.exe, rename SqlWriter.exe.old back to SqlWriter.exe, and start the service again.

Answer (score 3):

This requires stopping and starting the SQL Service, but will get you access to the SQL Server Instance if you are a local admin on the server.

Run this from an elevated command prompt.

Substitute the service name for `mssqlserver` if you have a named instance or SQL Express i.e. `mssql$sqlexpress`

Substitute your domain and account name for `BUILTIN\administrators` if you do not want to grant `sysadmin` for all local administrators and want just your account.

Note: the `/m` SQLCMD switch is single user mode and only a SQLCMD connection will be accepted. This is to keep from being locked out by a service that connects before I can get connected.

I have put these commands in a `.bat` file and ran it from an elevated command prompt. That makes the outage very short.

As always, test on a dev instance before you go running against production.

```sh
net stop mssqlserver

net start mssqlserver /mSQLCMD

sqlcmd -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 

net stop mssqlserver 

net start mssqlserver 

sqlcmd -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```